# IsVisible binding can only hide element in Android

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui

I have an element on a page in .NET MAUI, which should only be shown when a user has unread notifications. I have set a property on my viewmodel and is binding it to the isVisible property of element like this:

```
IsVisible="{Binding HasUnreadNotifications}"
```

The property is being requestet from the server, so it will take a short while until the HasUreadNotifications will be set. However when it is set to true and raised (invoke the OnPropertyChanged event), then the element does not show.

I have figured out, that if the default state is true, and the server responds false, then the element is correctly hidden.

So it seems that in android the IsVisible can only hide elements. Can this really be true?

The project is an upgrade from a previous Xamarin-project.

My property is very plain:

```
public bool _hasUnreadNotifications = false;
    public bool HasUnreadNotifications 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _hasUnreadNotifications;
        }
        set
        {
            _hasUnreadNotifications = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(HasUnreadNotifications));
        }
    }
```

I use prism with my view-models inheriting from BindableBase, which has Raise property changed.

The setter is invoked after a service call:

```
private async Task GetNotificationStatisticsAsync()
{
    try
    {
       var result = await _notificationsService.GetLastSeenNotificationStatistics();
       UnreadNotificationsCount = result.Count;
       HasUnreadNotifications = result.Count > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        UnreadNotificationsCount = 0;
    }
}
```

The service call is invoked in the navigate callback:

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await DoUpdateUserInformation());
}
```

The item I'm trying to show is in a regular ContentPage housed within a couple of grinds for layout:

```
<ContentPage ...>    
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, AutColumnSpacing="12">
        <controls:ArterIconButton Grid.Column="0"  Command="{Binding ShowNotificationsCommand}" Icon="{StaticResource Fa-Bell}" />
        <Border Grid.Column="0" InputTransparent="True" IsVisible="{Binding HasUnreadNotifications}" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 12.5" VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Red}">
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextSmallBold}" Text="{Binding UnreadNotificationsCount}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

P.s: In iOS the behavior is as expected: The property can be false and then the element is hidde, but when it is set to true, the element is shown.

Comment: This is not enough code to understand what might be going on. Please add all the relevant code to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added more code. I have tried to remove all un-related stuff.

Comment: @SimonBob `So it seems that in android the IsVisible can only hide elements. Can this really be true?` It's not true. Android IsVisible can show and hide elements. I create a project and use ViewModel to bind one to the IsVisible property of an element. Then fire its change by button click Command. It works well. I think it has something wrong with the section of the service call. You can break the point to check it.

Comment: I have set breakpoints, and the service call works well. The property is being correctly updated. I have tried with and without Task.Run, but with no difference.

Comment: Also, generally in android, I'm not really trusting the rendering in MAUI. If i add and remove elements in lists and observable collections these changes are not always reflected in e.g. bindablelayouts and collectionviews. I was just thinking that IsVisible is such a basic feature, that I must be able to get this to work.

Comment: Well, as you said that the service call works well, and the property is being correctly updated. So, it has something wrong with IsVisible. You can raise this issue to GitHub for it.